# Unique html item ID in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, uniqueidentifier

I am building a drag'n'drop gui builder in Javascript. So far so good.

As I add items to the GUI and configure them; I have two mechanisms for addressing them:

- the 'class' - which I use for doing things to ***all instances*** of an item (eg CSS, generic functionality and so on and so forth) and which I can bind javascript libraries to... and I can make full use of polymorphic class names (ie class="name1 name2 name3 name4" with different things bound to each class name...)
- the 'id' - which refers to ***this particular instance*** of a text box or a paragraph and which I can bind javascript libraries to

My problem is this: the 'id' must be unique across all html items on the page (by definition) so how do I ensure this? I need to get all the id's of all the items and then maintain some sort of state table.

Starting from a blank bit of html this is pretty reasonable - but I need to start from a partly created bit of html with a mixture of existing 'id's - some of which will be in my unique scheme and some of which wont be...

The way to do this best ***ought*** to be a solved problem.

Suggestions, tips, examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The best way to do this will depend entirely upon the structure and organization of your javascript.**  Assuming that you are using objects to represent each of your GUI elements you could use a static counter to increment your ids:

```
// Your element constructor
function GuiElement() {
    this.id = GuiElement.getID();
}
GuiElement.counter = 0;
GuiElement.getID = function() { return 'element_' + GuiElement.counter++; };
```

Of course you probably have more than one type of element, so you could either set each of them up so that they have their own counter (e.g. form_1, form_2, label_1, label_2) or so that they all share a counter (e.g. element_1, element_2, element_3), but either way you will probably want them to inherit from some base object:

```
// Your base element constructor
function GuiElement(tagName, className) {
    this.tagName = tagName;
    this.className = className;
}
GuiElement.counter = 0;
GuiElement.getID = function() { return 'element_' + GuiElement.counter++; };
GuiElement.prototype.init = function() {
    this.node = document.createElement(this.tagName);
    this.node.id = this.id = GuiElement.getID();
    this.node.className = this.className;
}

// An element constructor
function Form() {
    this.init();
}
Form.prototype = new GuiElement('form', 'form gui-element');

// Another element constructor
function Paragraph() {
    this.init();
}
Paragraph.prototype = new GuiElement('p', 'paragraph gui-element');
```

You could also go this route if you would rather keep some variables "private":

```
// Your element constructor constructor
var GuiElement = (function() {
    var counter = 0;
    function getID() {
        return 'element_' + counter++;
    }
    return function GuiElement(tagName, className) {
        return function() {
            this.node = document.createElement(tagName);
            this.node.id = this.id = getID();
            this.node.className = className + ' gui-element';
            this.className = className;
        };
    }
})();

// Create your element constructors
var Form = GuiElement('form', 'form'),
    Paragraph = GuiElement('p', 'paragraph');

// Instantiate elements
var f1 = new Form(),
    f2 = new Form(),
    p1 = new Paragraph();
```

**Update:** If you need to verify that an id is not already in use then you could add the check you and of the getID methods:

```
var counter = 0;
function getID() {
    var id = 'element_' + counter++;
    while(document.getElementById(id)) id = 'element_' + counter++;
    return id;
}
```

Comment: Aah, I see I wasn't clear enough in my statement of the problem. I start with a non-blank bit of html which may already contain ids, some of them conforming to my 'id incrementation' standards, and some not... I have edited the main body to reflect this...

Comment: Oh, yeah, and as you run it only on instantiating the gui builder the cost of find the first 'next' id is negligible...

Answer (score 2):

```
function uniqueId() {
    return 'id_' + new Date().getTime();
}
```

Comment: Mostly guaranteed to be unique for this session... Would probably be good enough...

Comment: or even easier: increment id (e.g. ID0, ID1, ID2 ... ID130 etc) by one each time you add one element to the page...

Comment: Yeah, but what happens if I then edit an existing GUI? - I need to know what I have got up to...

Comment: How would you know the ID of a particular element when you want to access it?

Comment: I use a class name to get all the items that I'm interested in and then I generate an array of id's (but I can't have a name class with other id's on the page...)

Comment: Well I stuck this in as the interim solution to get going and found that Javascript can create HTML fragments under the granularity of Date().getTime() - ie multiple elements where being created with the same ID so caveat lector...

Comment: If unique Id() is called many times per millisecond, many ids are duplicates!

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using the Prototype library (or want to check it out), you can use the Element.identify() method.

Otherwise, Darin's response is a good idea as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
function generateId() {
    var chars = "0123456789abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
        string_length = 8,
        id = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < string_length; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        id += chars.substring(rnum, rnum + 1);
    }

    return id;
}
```

Close enough to unique is good enough.  Don't use the `Date()` solution unless you're only generating a single ID at any given time...